# Weird lighting and how many tris for games

Tags: modeling, light, shaders, unreal-engine

I'm new to blender, I am looking to create a game using unreal 4.

That being said, how many tris are too much? currently working on a character's boots and am riding at over 2000 for just one of them...

Also, after working on the shape for a while the lighting is acting weird on just one part, as shown in the pictures.

Why? and how can I fix?

Thanks. 
[image: Weird Shadow]

[image: View from another angle]

Comment: generally speaking, the polly count should be kept as low as possible without sacrificing too much detail. Remember that game engines render things real time. If it takes a few minutes to render the scene, you will probably have miserably slow frame rate in your game.

Comment: Related question about the shading issue: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16602/color-faces-with-wrong-normals/16608#16608

Comment: please limit your Questions to one question per post. The [shading issue already has an answer](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3606/why-are-some-faces-in-my-mesh-darker) and is separate from the question about how many triangles is appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Generally you want to keep the rule to making a really high poly mesh and then baking the normals of the hi resolution mesh on a low poly version of it. So you get the illusion of a really high poly looking model in game. That's what all the next gen games are doing. If anything , it's defintely not the foot of a character you want to spend your polygons on ... any artist must know it's the face and the eyes of a character that would require the most details. Cos that's where your audience will focus on.

As for the feet of your character , it's not the shader looking strange but rather you need to improve the model, or rather improve on your observation of real life objects. You can use GLSL shader to improve the viewport's feedback while you sculpt. I will add a few images below.

[image]

You can observe here that I have a high poly model on the right. And a low poly one on the left. After sculpting I bake those information out onto the low poly version to get this ...

[image]

From here on out , I will leave it to you to run through google for tutorials
using keywords in your search eg. Blender Baking Normals and Blender High Density Mesh Sculpting and Blender Dynamic Topology Sculpting.