# Removing Double Faces

Tags: modeling, modifiers, edit-mode

[image: "Double Skin"]

Hi.  I'm new to Blender and started making modeling, till I ran into a problem.

I need help to remove a "Double Skin" as shown in the screenshot, as well as those blue lines.

The issue happened as I joined two objects and added mirror modifier.  I already tried removing doubles as well as removing modifiers, but to no avail.

Thank You!

Comment: the blue lines are the  display of the [normals](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/16609/2217).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When removing doubles you need to have everything selected. If that still doesn't work try selecting a section of one 'skin' and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> to select everything connected to it and then delete it.

Comment: This will be on edit or object mode?  Again, I'm new, barely three days using Blender

Comment: This will be in edit mode.

Comment: Oh and the blue lines are the face normals. There is nothing wrong with having them, they just show which way each face is pointing. To get rid of those, have your mouse over the viewport, press n to bring up the properties panel and under the Mesh Display header click on the little face icon.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  Manage to work with the blue line.  The "Skin" however, seem to be attach to the center edge.  If I try delete it, it deletes everything.

Comment: Also note that remove doubles has a "tolerance" setting, which by default is not zero... you can adjust it.

Comment: Thank You All!!! Manage to solve the issue by reloading a previous save file.  I still thank you all for giving me helpful tips I had no knowledge off.

Comment: If you ever have an issue like this again, simply select the center edge loop, hide it with H, then use the select linked method in my answer. After that unhide the center edge with Alt-H and you should be good to go.